# Return pointer to a subarray

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

Let's say I have function that has a char array as its parameter and char* as its return type. I want to return a pointer to the subarray of the parameter array.

For example : `char str[] = "hi billy bob";`

I want my function to return `"billy bob"`;

Let's say in the body of my function I was able to get the index 
of where I want the subarray to start.

```
char* fun(const char s1[]) {
    int index = a random int;
    /* char *p = *(s1[index1]);  */   
    return p;
}
```

I'm having trouble with the commented out line.

Comment: Your function could not possible return that, because `Billy bob` is not anywhere in it.

Comment: Your commented out line `/* char *p = *(s1[index1]);  */` is trying to dereference a `char` (because `s1[index1` is a `char`) which won't work, but you really wanted the address of the memory location holding the character, which is given by `&`. You needed: `char *p = &s1[index1];`.  That would work correctly, and since the array `s1` was passed into the function, you are not returning the address of a local variable, so it's safe.  You'd need to check that the index was in range; one of the arguments to the 'a random int' should be `strlen(s1)` or perhaps just `s1`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use

```
const char *p = &str[index]; /* may also write p = str + index */
return p;
```

The above takes the address of the character at index `index` -- which is a pointer to char array beginning at this index. The string continues until the first `'\0'` character which is the end of the original `str`.

In your case, if you want the output to be "billy bob" (Note that you cannot change the capitalization unless you modify the string or return a new one) you should set `index = 3;`.

It gets more involved when you want to take a substring of `str`. Then you either have to set `str[end_index]='\0'` or use `malloc` to allocate a new array and copy the relevant part.

#### Some information regarding the two syntax options

In C, the expression `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a+i)`. I.e., take the pointer `a`, move it forward `i` elements (`char`s in your case) and then return the element at the resulting address.

If you prefix `a[i]` with an `&` operator to get the address of that character. So `&a[i]` may be written as `&*(a+i)`. The operators '&' and '*' cancel each other and you are left with `a+i`.

Comment: Or `char *p = s1; return s1 + index`? And `s1` is a very lazy name for a variable.

Comment: Regarding the use of `s1`. Lazy indeed but that's what the comment in the original question had (I missed the `str` parameter). Regarding the `str+index` -- yes it's a valid option but I think beginners prefer the more explicit  `&str[index]` syntax.

Answer (score -1):

What you want is this

```
char *random_sub_string(const char *string) 
{
    size_t length;
    if (string == NULL)
        return NULL;
    length = strlen(string);
    return string + rand() % length;
}
```

Comment: The point of the question is not to return a random substring. It is being assumed that some index into the string has been calculated. The question is asking how to return a string beginning at that index.

Answer (score -1):

```
char *fun(const char str[])
{
    int index = x; /* where `x' is some non-negative value less than the
                      length of the input string */
    return str + index;
}
```

This is the cleanest way of returning the string you're looking to return. The main idea here is that, in C, a string is defined as a null-terminated array of characters. Null-terminated means the array contains the `\0` character, and the location of the `\0` denotes the end of the string. Moreover, a `char[]` and `char *` are both pointers to a char. Thus, they can be accessed in the same way. In the return statement above, we make use of pointer arithmetic to compute a pointer to a substring of the input string. If you're not familiar with pointer arithmetic, it would be a good idea to read up on it.

Comment: I don't see how your answer improves anything on the answers already given. And I would make `x` a parameter in this situation, why didn't you? You are used to global variables for this perhaps.

Comment: @iharob The other answer posted was originally a bit unclear and avoided addressing the concepts that led to the OP's misunderstanding. I'm glad to see that answer has since been improved. I think you are still misunderstanding the question. The OP is supposing that some arbitrary index will be computed by his/her function. We don't know or care what that index is. So, without loss of generality, `index` should be assigned some computed value, subject to the constraints I mentioned. There are no global variables in this example, and the OP's question does not involve an `x` parameter.